# JavaFX format Math during input

Tags: math, javafx, latex, javafx-8

Is there a way that a mathematical expression can be formatted in JavaFX during input? Something like a TextArea that behaves exactly as the [mathquill](http://mathquill.com/) editor, which is for web applications?

If not, would it be possible to create a custom `TextField` / `TextArea` to provide such functionality? I have not yet looked into this so any guidance or suggestions are welcome :)

The only workaround I came up with is to input the expression as a String and convert it to an image using [jLaTeXmath](https://github.com/opencollab/jlatexmath), which is not preferred as the end result should be an editable equation.

Short example on embedding [jLaTeXmath](https://github.com/opencollab/jlatexmath):

This is done by converting a TeX expression to a `BufferedImage` that can be placed on a Pane. See below the code for the conversion:

```
/**
     * Converts LaTeX code to a BufferedImage
     * @param latex
     */
    public static BufferedImage latexToImage(String latex){

        String start  ="\\begin{array}{l}";
        start += latex;
        start += "\\end{array}";

        TeXFormula formula = new TeXFormula(start);
        // Note: Old interface for creating icons:
        //TeXIcon icon = formula.createTeXIcon(TeXConstants.STYLE_DISPLAY, 20);
        // Note: New interface using builder pattern (inner class):
        TeXIcon icon = formula.new TeXIconBuilder().setStyle(TeXConstants.STYLE_DISPLAY).setSize(65f).build();
        icon.setInsets(new Insets(1, 1, 1, 1));





        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(icon.getIconWidth(), icon.getIconHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        Graphics2D g2 = image.createGraphics();
        g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Clear);
//      g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2.fillRect(0,0,icon.getIconWidth(),icon.getIconHeight());
        JLabel jl = new JLabel();
        jl.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 0));

        g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src);
        icon.paintIcon(null, g2, 0, 0);
        /*
        File file = new File("Example2.png");
        try {
            ImageIO.write(image, "png", file.getAbsoluteFile());
        } catch (IOException ex) {}
*/

        return image;
    }
```

The image can then be converted and set in a ImageView in JavaFX as folllows:

```
BufferedImage bimage = latexToImage("a = 2 \cdot x");
Image image = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bimage , null);
// have an ImageView in your scene and set the image
imgView.setImage(image );
```

Comment: Maybe you can explain in what way jLaTeXmath is not sufficient. Also it's not clear what you mean by "during input". I think it would help if you state exactly what you're trying to do; "something similar to ..." leaves a lot of room for different interpretations.

Comment: My apologies for not being clear in the question.  I'm looking to render the equation as the user types it. For example a TextArea that performs exactly like the mathquill input.   jLatexMath can produce an image from a mathematical expression in String form, whereas I'm looking to produce an editable equation, not an image.

Comment: Would you mind showing how you embedded jLaTeXmath in a JavaFX application (short example)? That would interest me a great deal. Also, have you found a solution for your problem of formatting math formulae in JavaFX the way mathquill does it? Thx.

Comment: @user3451767 I added example code to convert a LaTeX expression to a BufferedImage which can be displayed. Unfortunately I have not yet found a solution. Do you have any ideas how one can achieve this?

Comment: Great. Thx., indeed. Could you add a little test scene and stage that implements one example. I am still rather new to java and struggeling a bit in making use of your code.

Comment: Maybe https://guppy.js.org/site/ could be interesting to you.

Answer (score 0):

The next coming versions of JavaFX support MathML by using a HTMLEditor Control :

- JavaFX 8 Update 192 included in Java 8 Update 192
- JavaFX 11.

Follow this link Java [Early Access Download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/ea-jsp-142245.html) to reach the early access to these versions.

I'm afraid that what you are looking for doesn't exist yet.

There is a project in the [JavaFX GitHub Reprository](https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx/issues/118), but it's long term project.

About MathQuill, it seems that it is a JavaScript code. Or HTMLEditor uses an implementation of WebKit and can execute JavaScript code. It could be a short term solution.